# Web application access user's file system

Tags: javascript, security, web, filesystems

I am creating a web application for my client. The application will be installed on a dedicated server within corporate network.
He wants to see the list of his local files (from his local PC) on the web page. He means that any visitor can see the list of his local files from some folder.

***I know*** that the web application cannot have access to visitor's file system. Browser limits this by design. *Of course, there might be some browser extensions and applets and flash apps or even hacks.. But this is not that case.*

But how can I explain this to him? He points me to the 'save as' or 'load file' dialogs and say that other applications can do this. I don't know how to explain him that this is just a browser's interaction.

I tried to google for some links to proofs, but cannot find something quickly.

Can you guys give me some links to the documents describing inability to access user's folder from web application?

Comment: Interestingly it does not look like there is highly visible authoritative material to support this well-known restriction indeed! Of course there are many workarounds, depending on what your client allows you to do / install. He might request that after having seen some NAS features for online file access. If that can help you, I could only come up with books and small texts: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/security/WS485a42d56cd196415cc29732124ef23decb-7ff7.html and https://books.google.com/books?id=ntsJqzfwFhkC&pg=PA258&lpg=PA258#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: in 2022 they will be able to access client filesystems... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API

Comment: It still will take years to get this implemented everywhere. And it seems it did not go far away from file/directory picker where you select a directory first in a window deliberately.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally I did a compilation of some quotations and it is done..

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Security

> scripts run in a sandbox in which they can only perform Web-related
>   actions, not general-purpose programming tasks like creating files

https://www.us-cert.gov/publications/securing-your-web-browser

> JavaScript, also known as ECMAScript, is a scripting language that is used to make websites more interactive. There are specifications in the JavaScript standard that restrict certain features such as accessing local files.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_API/Introduction#restrictions

> Because the file system is sandboxed, a web app cannot access another app's files. You also cannot read or write files to an arbitrary folder (for example, My Pictures and My Documents) on the user's hard drive.

Comment: in 2022 they will be able to access client filesystems... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API

Answer (score 1):

[Mozilla. File System API Restrictions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_API/Introduction#restrictions)

> Because the file system is sandboxed, a web app cannot access another
>   app's files. You also cannot read or write files to an arbitrary
>   folder (for example, My Pictures and My Documents) on the user's hard
>   drive.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this document rocks?

http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/file-dir-sys.html#security-considerations

Section 4.1

An application can request temporary or persistent storage space. Temporary storage may be easier to get, at the UA's discretion [looser quota restrictions, available without prompting the user], but the data stored there may be deleted at the UA's convenience, e.g. to deal with a shortage of disk space.

Conversely, once persistent storage has been granted, data stored there by the application should not be deleted by the UA without user intervention. The application may of course delete it at will. The UA should require permission from the user before granting persistent storage space to the application.

This API specifies the standard origin isolation in a filesystem context, along with persistence of data across invocations. Applications will likely use temporary storage for caching, and if it's still around from a previous session, it is often useful. Persistent data, on the other hand, is useless if you can't access it again the next time you're invoked. However, even persistent data may be deleted manually by the user [either through the UA or via direct filesystem operations].

Answer (score 0):

What about arguing with the Client-Server model?
You send a request to the server (website request, file or whatever) and the webserver can respond.
There's no direct file system access on the server (webserver in between) and the client can choose what he sends to the server (file picker dialogue in browser).

Comment: No way. You can open the https://www.sumopaint.com/ online application and it has "Open From My Computer" menu item. Clicking on it you can see the list of your local files and even mounted drives. So - magic - it can access the files. :(

Comment: No, the client - the user - wants to send exactly the stuff chosen in this dialougue from the browser to the server. He's the client, he can choose what he sends.

Comment: OMG, I have opened file dialog from so many websites. So now they all know what files are on my computer. **File Dialog** is opened on client's machine server does not even knows if someone opened that dialog or not. Even your script on page cannot know what files are showing in the dialog. It can only access the file that user selects to upload nothing else.

Comment: You know this. I know that. But I need the prooflinks to show him :)

Comment: The dialogue is opened by the browser the client is running. That's it: The client's choice.
No need to "proove" anything more.

Comment: People trust the things that they see. He sees that click on the link on the web application brings the list of the files from his computer. He does not believe that I cannot show the list of his local files.Give me the link to the most boring tech spec and I am saved!

Comment: Ok, one last try, then I'll give up: Why the hell he think the dialogue is opened from the server??? Just let him save the website's html and disconnect from any network connection and then let him click that damn file chooser button again.

Comment: Of course this might be javascript working on that html page. It does not need network connection.

Answer (score -2):

The html below allows me to see a list of local files.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click on the "Choose File" button to upload a file:</p>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It does not. You cannot list visitor's files on the page. Page's javascript code does not have access to the list of files.

Comment: It does for me and W3Schools seems to agree: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_file.asp

Comment: No, this is not what it means. Web page (javascript) does not have access to the file system. Popup dialog to select a file is the only way for user to select a file and upload it. And only after that the content can be available for the page. You may read the links in the answers above for the details.

Comment: I am sorry, @baldr, but I can indeed see a list of local files when I use the above HTML. I did not claim that could 'list visitor's files on the page'. I agree that I do not see them in my browser. I agree that the list is not in a web page.  I also agree that the browser does not have access to the local filesystem beyond what is offered in something like the file input type in a form.

Comment: And this is what was my original question about. The client wanted to see his local files when he opens remote web page. And I state that this is not possible at this moment. And I state that your answer is wrong and it could confuse people who might look for an answer too. I'd downwote it one more time if I could.

Comment: My answer may not have been the best for the user, but it is factually correct. I state again that the html I gave allows me to see a list of local files.

Comment: Sure. Could you please make a demo page, upload it to the remote server and give a link so I could see a list of my local files?

Comment: As you are an expert in all things web, I am sure you know how to use the html above to get a list of local files. I am not sure why you ask me to make a demo page when the html above is exactly that. As for putting it on a server, why not just save it as demo.html and open it in your own browser? But of course you know those things.

Comment: Of course I know. An of course it does not work.