# Fetch names of files and and folders off a local drive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a website to manage my Videos and TV shows. I want to do this without a local server. That is kind of a problem, because I can't use Technologies like AJAX and PHP.

My problem is that I want a my site to scan for the files on my local drive. I want to read my local files, not the ones on the server. Is that even possible? Or does my computer block this kind of functions? In order to protect the my privacy?

I'd be glad  if someone could tell me which programming language could handle that kind of stuff. Or weather it is completely impossible without a server?

Comment: Visual Studio Code ... It's free and can make program run on Win, Mac, Linux

Comment: [Web application access user's file system](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33746680/215552)

Answer (score 0):

without a local server or a local executable, it's impossible, because navigators are running in a "sand box"...

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript doesn't have access to the local filesystem from the browser

This is mostly due to security limitations. In a browser environment, you're limited to accessing the current window and core browser features through some predefined APIs, but that's about it. You can't technically read a file from the user's machine without it being uploaded through the browser.

### But there are some ways around that

If you already know enough HTML and JS to build a webapp, you could look into learning node.js and its desktop shell, [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/). It's the same technologies you would use on the web within a container and with bindings to the node.js APIs like file system reads and writes. It's a huge ecosystem to wrap your head around, but there are loads of documentation and tutorials online, and it's a great way to build desktop apps with the languages and tools you're already familiar with.