# Using node.js scripts in index.html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web-scraping

I have a script that is used to scrape data off of reddit called scraper.js. It looks like this:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var fs = require('fs');

request("https://www.reddit.com/r/all", function(error, response, body) {
if(error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
}
console.log("Status code: " + response.statusCode);

var $ = cheerio.load(body);

$('div#siteTable > div.link').each(function( index ) {
    var title = $(this).find('p.title > a.title').text().trim();
    var time = $(this).find('p.tagline').text().trim();
    var user = $(this).find('a.author').text().trim();


    console.log("Title: " + title);
    console.log("Author: " + user);
    console.log("Time: " + time);
    // possibly wrap this part in <li> tags???
    fs.appendFileSync('reddit.txt', title + '\n');

});
});
```

This does exactly what I want it to do when run:

```
node script.js
```

in my terminal, but how do I go about getting this to happen in my index.html file?

Comment: You don't; you run something on the back end that hits Reddit. You know they have an API, right?!

Comment: Try [browserify](http://browserify.org/)

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to run node.js from within a client-side browsing context.  This isn't impossible, using things like browserify, but you will have to eleminate your dependency on `fs` which can't be used in a browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web application access user's file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33746680/web-application-access-users-file-system)

Answer (score 0):

you can use Node Express for both client side and server side together.

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```

```html
file name use index.ejs

<h1>test</h1>
<div ><%= title %></div>
```