# Unable to Open .exe file by clicking on an HTML link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, exe

I want to add an html link inside our intranet site, and when the user click on the link it should open an `.exe` file that are already installed inside all the users machines. now i try this code:-

```
<a href = "C:\Program Files\Cisco Systems\VPN\vpngui.exe">VPN</a>
```

but i tested this on IE-11, Chrome & FireFox. and it only worked on IE. here is a more detailed about how things worked:-

- On IE. it worked well, where i got this dialog >> i click on Run and the application opened well.

[image]

- On FireFox. i got this error, when i click on the link:
  [image]
- On chrome. when i click on the link, i got this dialog, but if i click on Keep >> then Open >> i got an error that there is a missing .dll file!!
  [image]

[image]

So can anyone advice on this please?

Answer (score 1):

I will try to be the less sarcastic as I can...
You say that a link targeting a local file on a user machine **works** on IE? That is bad! Really!
*I'm doubtful about the assertion... I alway said IE sucks.. But to that point! I'm surprised.*

No one wants an http(s) web page to run a local file on click! **No one**.
That is an obvious security issue.

A web page has to run it's functionalities on server-side.
The "window" **SHOULD BE WATERTIGHT** between the net and the user's local hard drive.

Still any question?

Comment: so you are saying we should not do this ? we should not add a link to open a .exe file found on users' machine,, even if IE can achieve this?

Comment: I don't know what you want to do... But my opinion is that no browser should have that working. IE is a crap (again, my opinion). Here is what I found about getting access to the local file system: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem) and [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33803293/2159528) ;)