# How to launch another application by passing c drive path in react web application?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on react web application.I want to launch application which is already into the system on c drive.So for eg, I will click on some button at that moment it should read c drive path (say C:\Program Files\VLC\VLC.exe) and launch/open VLC player. Also, I have another drive (say, \d:\test.mpg) path where playable file is located which I wanted to play with that player at the same moment when its launch. So I want to pass path "C:\Program Files\VLC\VLC.exe \d:\test.mpg" and open file. Here, not sure how I can pass outside application path to access file.
I have not tried anything as I have no idea how to do so any help would be really appreciate. TIA!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access a visitor's file system from a web application. This would be a tremendously dangerous security vulnerability if any web browser allowed this.

Resources about this are listed in [other Stack Overflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33746680/web-application-access-users-file-system)

If you want a React application to have access to this kind of information you need to create a desktop application that the intended user can then use.

For instance Electron can load and render a web application with a Node.js instace available which can then access a user's system, but again, there are extremely serious [security concerns](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#checklist-security-recommendations) that should (one might argue must) be considered thoroughly before proceeding down that path.

Comment: How Electron works with react app? Can you please provide some code snippet for that?