# copy images in angular

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8

I am working on a angular application. I have some images in my assets folder. Project structure is as follows.

```
src -> assests  -> images -> myImage.png
```

I want to load this image file in angular and copy it into C drive. I don't want to use node for that. I want to do it in angular only. How I can do that?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33746680/web-application-access-users-file-system) question. It's not really a duplicate, but it answers your question

Comment: Not posssible . You can't never reach local path with frontend apps like angular.