# Is it possible to display user images with javascript without having to save them to some backend?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to display user images without having to save them online.
I have the user's absolute path to the image on their computer but when I try to display that it treats it as a relative path.
Is it possible to display an image with only frontend work and no backend? I want my app to be as trustworthy as possible so I don't want to save the user's images online.

Comment: You can convert your image to base64 and display. [This will help you](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-to-base64)

Comment: does this answers your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33746680/web-application-access-users-file-system

Comment: This makes no sense. If the images aren't online they can't be shown on a website. What exactly do you think is untrustworthy about saving the pictures on your server along with your html pages? Someone suggested using base64 but the end result is very similar - publicly viewable images whose data is stored on a public website. The only difference in that case is the data is embedded in a html page instead of stored in separate files. What problem are you actually trying to solve with this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

@JamacCrew, Welcome to StackOverflow!
Your application cannot have access to the machine of a user so you cannot display images stored on their machines. You don't want to save the images on your server, so your user will have to give you the link to the images that are stored on a platform like dropbox or google. You can then save these links in your database and use them to display the images.

Comment: Thanks very much. Is there a framework or a form of requests I can make to display a folder of images from google drive that you know of?

Comment: To display the contents of a folder, you will have an access link to have each content of the folder. Think of it just like all the pages of your website. they are all in a folder and you have a route/link that you can call to access them.